# how to do conditional rendering and non-conditional rendering of both components in Map function react -native

Tags: react-native

i want to  display ItemName and if ItemDeliveryStatus==1 then show disabled TextInput else  display  editable TextInput  inside Map function react-native

```
const [arrayList, setArraylist] = useState([
        { id: 0,  ItemName: 'A',   ItemDeliveryStatus:1 },
        { id: 1, , ItemName: 'B', ItemDeliveryStatus:1 },
        { id: 2,  ItemName: 'C', ItemDeliveryStatus:1  },
        { id: 3,  ItemName: 'D', ItemDeliveryStatus:1  },
      ]);


{
   arrayList.map((items,index)=>{
     return <View>
              <Text >{items.ItemName}</Text>

          if(items.ItemDeliveryStatus== 1){
            return <View> 
                      <TextInput   editable={false} /> 
                   </View>
           }else
           {
                <View> 
                  <TextInput   editable={true} /> 
                </View>
            }

     </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can embed an expression in JSX component using curly braces, with ternary operator for condition, so the following should work:

```
{ items.ItemDeliveryStatus == 1 ?
  (<View> 
     <TextInput   editable={false} /> 
   </View>) : 
  (<View> 
     <TextInput   editable={true} /> 
   </View>)
}
```

It will work inside return of the component.
For example:

```
...
return (
  <View>
    { 
      items.ItemDeliveryStatus == 1 ?
      (<View> 
         <TextInput   editable={false} /> 
       </View>) : 
      (<View> 
         <TextInput   editable={true} /> 
       </View>)
    }
  </View>
)
```

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@shevchenko27/bossy-candies), made a snack for you, with complete code.

Comment: if it helped please upvote and mark as accepted answer so if others come to your question they will see the info that helped